# Do All-Day Calendar alerts still notify you if you power up after the start time but still during the event duration?

Tags: notifications, calendar, ventura

I have been trying to make my all-day calendar alerts show up since I loaded 13.4.  The default time is 9am the day of the alert.  I power on the computer at about 10am.  Before Ventura, I would get all of that days alerts right after power up.  Now I see nothing.  If, however, I leave the computer on all night, they will be there.  This is a change from pre-Ventura.  I have re-loaded my operating system, tried as a new user, called Apple Care.  I also logged out of iCloud, then set all day events in my "on my mac" calendars, but still no notification past the start time.  Nothing has helped. I have enclosed screen shots of Calendar Settings and Calendar Notification Preferences.  I am running 13.4.1.  I have also tried this on my other Mac, a neighbor's mac and my iphone.  None will give me my alert if powered up after the start time.[image: Calendar Settings]

[image: Notification Settings]